# Trying to take the file extension out of my URL

Tags: html, file, url

Curious on how to take the file extension out of my URL to make it appear as "https://thedigitalagetech.info/" instead of "https://thedigitalagetech.info/index.html."

Comment: what are u using? PHP?

Comment: No, HTML. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it unless you are using any sort of server like Apache or Nginx. You will find your desired option with a server side solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your apache server is configured.

You can try to create a .htaccess file in your root directory, and add the following content to see if it works.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

We can only trial and error because we don't know your set up.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options like: .htaccess, folder structure or JavaScript.

**Solution 1.**

As suggested by other users the best solution for this is probably using a script in your .htaccess file. But it's quitte difficult to understand if you're new to it. So your best option would be to search for a similar script in a tutorial or something.

**Solution 2.**

Another simple trick for a few pages would be to use the browsers way of showing index.html. Because it doesn't need to show index.html in the url if you just call the parent folder! As you might already have figured out you don't need to visit "https://thedigitalagetech.info/index.html" just visiting "https://thedigitalagetech.info" will already show you the index.html page. This is because when the browsers makes this request your server checks for a file called *index* if such a file exists it returns that one.

But ofcourse if you've got a page like services.html or contact.html then the url becomes something like "https://thedigitalagetech.info/contact.html" and I guess this is the part that you don't want. Instead of having a page called contact.html create a folder called *contact* and rename the contact.html to *index.html* inside that folder.
This way you could make a request to the folder and it will show the index.html of that folder. The request would look like this "https://thedigitalagetech.info/contact/"

So the folder structure is like:  **parts between () are folders*

```
 (public-html)    <-- root folder of your server
    index.html    <-- Your homepage
    (contact)     <-- a new folder
       index.html <-- Your old contact.html
    (services)    <-- a new folder
       index.html <-- Your old services.html
```

**Solution 3.**

You could use JavaScript I guess but only to hide the file extentsion in the url after they've already visited it. And you're actually adding a none excisting page to there browser history so I think it's really bad practice as well. But still it might be a solution for you.

```
function rewriteUrl()
{
     let newURL = window.location.href.split('.html')[0];
     history.pushState(null,null,newURL);
}
```